# Convert List<Class> to List<Class.property>

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, lambda

I am looking for an elegant way to convert a List where we remove the object information and keep only a specific property.

example: List< Fruit> becomes List with the property fruitColor (a String) kept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
var listOfFruit = ...;
var listOfColors = listOfFruit.map((e) => e.fruitColor).toList();
```

Comment: Yeah, without that you still have a lazy iterable.

Comment: Alternative: `var listOfColors = [...listOfFruit.map((e) => e.fruitColor)];`

Comment: I would consider that more obscure.  At least, if someone doesn't know ".toList", it's easy to google for.  "[..." not so much. :)  Plus, I think the spread would necessarily realize the map result, *then* copy it again into the list handed to the assignment.  Wasteful.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz We really don't know if Dart has some optimization for the `...` operator in cases like this. But yes, `toList()` is the most readable solution. But I find it important enough to learn people in general about the `...` operator so they know it is there in case you e.g. want to have content from multiple Iterables in your new `List` :)